Does "Fire & Blood" suggest Rhaenyra Targaryen's supporters back her mainly because she's allied with Daemon Targaryen?
In the "Inside the Episode" video for House of the Dragon Season 2, Episode 2, showrunner Ryan Condal made an interesting statement about Rhaenyra Targaryen's claim to the Iron Throne. He stated:

So much of [Rhaenyra's] claim is wrapped up in the realm's assurance that, yes, Rhaenyra will be queen, but at least she has Daemon Targaryen at her side.

You can find this quote at 5:25 in this video:



I initially thought Daemon's association might actually harm Rhaenyra's cause. After all, he's not exactly known for his diplomacy. Take his relationship with the Vale, for instance. Daemon isn't particularly liked there due to his poor treatment of his first wife, Lady Rhea Royce of Runestone, whom he callously referred to as his "bronze b---h". He even expressed disdain for the entire region, once quipping, "In the Vale, men are said to f--k sheep instead of women. I can assure you, the sheep are prettier."
Given Daemon's controversial reputation, I'm curious: Does Ryan Condal's statement actually reflect the views of Rhaenyra's and the Blacks' allies in the show's source material, Fire & Blood?
Are there any instances in the book where lords or nobles supporting the Blacks express a similar idea? For example, does anyone say something along the lines of, "We're supporting Rhaenyra as queen, but only because she's with Daemon Targaryen"?
Does Daemon's presence truly strengthen Rhaenyra's claim in the eyes of Westeros, or is this a perspective unique to the show?

I have a feeling it's less of their support for Daemon rather than her and more that they know Daemon is the best tactician in war so he's more likely to win out there. The only ones really on Rhaenyra's side because of Daemon are the Gold Cloaks. There are hints at this in the book but I'm not sure there's enough to constitute an answer.

Daemon was loved by the people of King's Landing, especially the City Watch (did you know, he was the one who gave them their gold cloaks, thus dubbing them the "Gold Cloaks"?)

From what I recall, no one really mentions this outright. There are however mentions from the green side that although Rhaenyra might want to sit the Throne, it'd be Daemon they'll have to contend with if she does. I'll do a re-read to find the relevant info...
